# Permission denied when use Winston

Tags: node.js, permission-denied, winston

In my nodeJS application I used "Winston" module for manage loggers. But when api run give me error given below.

```
node:internal/fs/utils:344
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/log/api/general'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1336:3)
```

I have run command `sudo chown -R /var/log/api/general`. But nothing change that error.
So I need some solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run `chown -R user /var/log/api/`